# How to include assembler listing from .A51 file in Keil .COD file?

Tags: c51

I am using Simplicity Studio Version 4 and it's built in Keil toolset to build an 8051 project.  My source code includes both C and assembly (.A51) files.  My setup creates a .COD file that includes the assembly listing of all of the C code, but not the .A51 code.

Is there a way to have all of the code included in the .COD file ?

Answer (score 0):

Verify that Simplicity Studio doesn't add the [NOPRINT directive to disable the printing of listings file](https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/a51/a51_noprint.htm). The Keil Ax51 assembler [generates listings files (.LST) by default](https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/a51/a51_print.htm), so it should do what you are asking for.